# Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding, two-way-binding

I just updated AndroidStudio to 3.0.1 from 2.3 version for one of my projects. AndroidStudio is now complaining about data binding issue when I try to build the project. I am using alpha release of gradle classpath

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha07

Error:(67, 17) Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text' with value type java.lang.String on null.
```

The line it's complaining about uses two-way data binding with `EditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/groupNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/text_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLength="@{viewModel.maxLength}"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@={viewModel.title}"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                app:filter="@{viewModel.inputType}"/>
```

The viewModel is an instance of class whose `parent(BaseViewModel)` extends `BaseObservable`.

Please note that it was working fine previously and it stopped working when I updated **AndroidStudio**. I tried **clean/build** and **invalidate/restart** options, no luck. I would really appreciate any pointers on what I'm missing.

Comment: 'viewModel.title' value is null. you can't pass null reference here.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. It would be set at runtime. The problem I'm having is at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case there were more than one issues. My app used many library modules residing on different repo. So I updated each module to use same gradle version( I used `3.1.0`).
Then I also updated the databinding library version.

 `dataBinding {
        enabled = true
        version '2.3.3'
    }`

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, spent hours on trying to find what is wrong with the code which was related to binding and inverse binding of spinner.

After upgrading Android studio to 3.0.1 and upgrading Gradle, the compile error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with databinding 3.1.0-alpha07/ Android Studio 3.1 Canary 7
I tried clean/restart too. I tried to downgrade to 3.1.0-alpha06, with no effect.
The only workaround that temporary worked, was to deleted every databinding lines with error, compile, and then put them again.